# What is Performance Impact on Calling Entity Framework await in Loop (vs sync)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous, async-await

I'm using EF6 and am trying to understand what is actually happening and what the performance impact is of putting an Async call to EF in a tight loop and running thousands of times.  That is, this loop:

```
using (var db = dbContext()) {
  vary query = db.MyTable.Where(...);
  cnt = 10000;
  for (var i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
    await query.ToListAsync();
}
```

My thinking is that at the end of the "using" statement, all of the 10000 will process sequentially.

When comparing this to calling synchronously (just query.ToList() without await), the exact same thing will happen and the performance should be identical.  My results show 1.5x difference in time running.

Question: Why is the time different and are my assumptions above correct?

Comment: Your query would execute at the await, at that point the loop will not continue until the query has returned. But what would you use this for? :)

Comment: Testing async vs not

Answer (score 0):

> My thinking is that at the end of the "using" statement, all of the
>   10000 will process sequentially.

No, they will be processed each time await...ToListAsync() is called.

> Question: Why is the time different and are my assumptions above
>   correct?

Because there is an overhead and therefore a performance penalty in this scenario to using async...ToListAsync() since you are trying to maximize single-threaded throughput.

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you make some additions, such as. But you need to know `cnt` in advance.

```
cosnt int cnt = 10000;
const int pageSize = 1000;

int pageNumber = 0;
var list = new List<MyTableRecord>();

using (var db = dbContext())
{
    for (var i = 0; i < cnt ; i++)
    {
        vary query = db.MyTable.Where(...).Skip(pageNumber++ * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
        list.AddRange(await query.ToArrayAsync());
    }
}
```

Note that `list` will likely blow up your computer's memory (`OutOfMemoryException`) if you'll try to load 1000 * 10000 records into it.

More realistic solution:

```
using (var db = dbContext())
{
    IEnumerable<MyTableRecord> rows;
    while ((rows = db.MyTable.Where(...).Skip(pageNumber++ * pageSize).Take(pageSize)).Any())
    {
        list.AddRange(rows);
    }
}
```

Note that you'll likely run all queries inside the same connection what can cause its timeout.